# Android 3.2 - Customize AlertDialog Button within DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-button, android-dialogfragment

I've created a class extending `DialogFragment` which returns an `AlertDialog` in it's onCreateDialog method, like [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).
The problem is, that I want to increase the standard (positive) button's height, but I cannot get a hold of it to change it's height.
When I do the following in the onCreateDialog method of the `DialogFragment`

```
mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(messageView)
            .setCustomTitle(titleView)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_button,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((ContextSwapUserInterface) getActivity()).instructionsAccepted();
                    }
                }
            )
            .create();

mAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setHeight(60);
```

I get an exception, which says "...unable to instantiate ComponentInfo..."
I guess this is because the Button is not instantiated properly at this point of time.
So I tried getting the button in my main activity, after I created the `DialogFragment` and called it's .show method:

```
// Create and show a new InstructionsDialogFragment
DialogFragment instructionsDialogFragment = InstructionsDialogFragment.newInstance(mInstructions);
instructionsDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Instructions Dialog");
((Button) instructionsDialogFragment.getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.button1)).setHeight(60);
```

I also tried the following, instead of the last line above:

```
((AlertDialog) instructionsDialogFragment.getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setHeight(60);
```

Both versions result in a NullPointerException. Is there any easy way to customize the `AlertDialog`'s Button while using a `DialogFragment`?

Answer (score 4):

Ok - Try gettin the button within the onActivityCreated method of the fragment. I did this for a listfragment, but it should do the same - check you have the right IDs etc.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Button b = (Button)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonID);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button Clicked",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });
```

Comment: I tried it in the onResume() method and it worked, though your suggestion probably works, too. Unfortunately I don't have any time to test it. Tanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use an `onShowListener` to modify the buttons
I had the same problem and i counldn't get my hand on Buttons until the dialog is shown `.show()`. i think the UI elements of the AlertDialog are not instantiated after `builder.create` but only after `.show()`.

```
mAlertDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setHeight(60);
        }
    });
```